# PHP get user if they fit group

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL problem which seem simple but I can't find the solution...

My table structure is as follows:

```
+----+----------------------+---------------+------------------+
| id | username             | primary_group | secondary_groups |
+----+----------------------+---------------+------------------+
|  1 | Username1            |      3        |       7,10       |
|  2 | Username2            |      7        |      3,5,10      |
|  3 | LongUsername         |      1        |       3,7        |
+----+----------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

I am trying to display users which are in Group 7 (either primary or secondary) groups.

My current SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE primary_group = 7 OR secondary_groups IN (7)
```

The issue I'm facing is the query above only displays the following output.

```
+----+----------------------+---------------+------------------+
| id | username             | primary_group | secondary_groups |
+----+----------------------+---------------+------------------+
|  1 | Username1            |      3        |       7,10       |
|  2 | Username2            |      7        |      3,5,10      |
+----+----------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

How would I display LongUsername in the list (my query doesn't work if there is a secondary_group before 7 (e.g. secondary_groups 3,6,7)

Any help/suggestions?

Comment: It should be `OR FIND_IN_SET('7', secondary_groups)`

Comment: But it would be better to normalize your schema to get rid of the comma-separated list.

Comment: So change it to SELECT * FROM users WHERE primary_group = 7 OR FIND_IN_SET('7', secondary_groups) ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said in my comment.

Comment: should I open a new question if I'm experiencing issues expanding from this query? (appears my issue looks to be grouping stuff)?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like your problem is different from the original, so a new question would be appropriate.