# Issue with grouping?

Tags: mysql

[I asked earlier about a solution to my problem which worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494704/php-get-user-if-they-fit-group) however now when I'm trying to get some information from a second table (that stores more information) I'm running into a few issues.

My tables are as follows

> Users

```
+----+----------------------+---------------+------------------+
| id | username             | primary_group | secondary_groups |
+----+----------------------+---------------+------------------+
|  1 | Username1            |      3        |       7,10       |
|  2 | Username2            |      7        |      3,5,10      |
|  3 | LongUsername         |      1        |       3,7        |
|  4 | Username3            |      1        |       3,10       |
|  5 | Username4            |      7        |                  |
|  6 | Username5            |      5        |      3,7,10      |
|  7 | Username6            |      2        |        7         |
|  8 | Username7            |      4        |                  |
+----+----------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

> Profile

```
+----+---------------+------------------+
| id |   facebook    |      steam       |
+----+---------------+------------------+
|  1 |  10049424151  |       11         |
|  2 |  10051277183  |       55         |
|  3 |  10051281183  |       751        |
|  4 |               |       735        |
|  5 |  10051215770  |      4444        |
|  6 |  10020210531  |      50415       |
|  7 |  10021056938  |     421501       |
|  8 |  10011547143  |       761        |
+----+---------------+------------------+
```

My SQL is as follows (based off the previous thread)

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, p.id, p.facebook, p.steam 
FROM users u, profile p 
WHERE p.id=u.id AND FIND_IN_SET(  '7', secondary_groups ) 
OR primary_group = 7 
GROUP BY u.id
```

The problem is my output is displayed as below

```
+----+----------------------+-------------+-------+
| id | username             |   facebook  | steam |
+----+----------------------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | Username1            | 10049424151 |  11   |
|  2 | Username2            | 10051277183 |  55   |
|  3 | LongUsername         | 10051281183 |  751  |
|  4 | Username4            | 10051215770 | 4444  |
|  5 | Username5            | 10049424151 |  11   |
|  6 | Username6            | 10049424151 |  55   |
+----+----------------------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: What's the problem with your output?

Comment: please show us the output that you expected

Comment: I`m guessing you are getting indeterminate values since you dont have aggregate functions on the columns not in the GROUP BY. username4 should have id 5

Comment: Normalize your schema - AS PREVIOUSLY ADVISED

Comment: You did not explain what you're trying to do, did not explain any sort of problem, and did not ask a question. (No, *Issue with grouping?* is not a question. It's a useless title you used for your post.) This site is for **specific questions** about **clearly stated problems you're experiencing**. You've provided neither of those things. Please complete the [tour] and read through the [help] pages, particularly [ask], and then come back here and [edit] your post. Be sure to also improve the title so that it's something descriptive; it should have content that will be useful to future readers.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, firstly imaging you possibly need () after "AND" and before "group by"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the problem is that `profile` rows with a `primary_group` of  `7` are getting matched to all `user` rows.  Remove the `GROUP BY`, and you'll be able to better see what is happening.

But that's just a guess. It's not clear what you are attempting to achieve.

I suspect you are getting tripped up with the order of precedence of the `AND` and `OR`. (The `AND` operator has a higher order of precedence than `OR` operator. That means the `AND` will be evaluated before the `OR`.)

The quick fix is to just add some parens, to override the default order of operations. Something like this:

```
WHERE p.id=u.id AND ( FIND_IN_SET('7',secondary_groups) OR primary_group = 7 )
   --               ^                                                        ^
```

The parens will cause the `OR` operation to be evaluated (as either TRUE, FALSE or NULL) and then the result from that will be evaluated in the `AND`.

Without the parens, it's the same as if the parens were here:

```
WHERE ( p.id=u.id AND FIND_IN_SET('7',secondary_groups) ) OR primary_group = 7 
   -- ^                                                 ^
```

With the `AND` condition evaluated first, and the result from that is operated on by `OR`.  This is what is causing profile rows with a 7 to be matched to rows in user with *different* id values.

---

A few pointers on style:

- avoid the old-school comma operator for join operations, and use the newer `JOIN` syntax
- place the join predicates (conditions) in the `ON` clause, other filtering criteria in the `WHERE` clause
- qualify *all* column references

As an example:

```
  SELECT u.id
       , u.username
       , p.id
       , p.facebook
       , p.steam
    FROM users u
    JOIN profile p
      ON p.id = u.id
   WHERE u.primary_group = 7
      OR FIND_IN_SET('7',u.secondary_groups) 
   ORDER BY u.id
```

We only need a `GROUP BY` clause if we want to "collapse" rows. If the `id` column is unique in both the `users` and `profile` tables, then there's no need for a `GROUP BY u.id`.  We can add an `ORDER BY` clause if we want rows returned in a particular sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, what exactly do you want to do with output, but you can't group informations like this. MySQL isn't really a classic programming language, it's more like powerful tool for set mathematics. So if you want to get informations based on corelations between two or more tables, first you write a select statement which contains raw data which you want to work with, like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM users u INNER JOIN profile p ON p.id=u.id
    GROUP BY u.id;
```

Now you select relevant data with WHERE statement:

```
    SELECT * FROM users u INNER JOIN profile p ON p.id=u.id WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(  '7', secondary_groups ) OR primary_group = 7
    GROUP BY u.id;
```

Now you should see grouped joined tables profile and users, and can start mining data. For example, if you want to count items in these groups, just add count function in SELECT and so on.
When debugging SQL, I highly recommend these steps:
1.) First, you should write down all corelations between data, all foreign keys between tables, so you will know if your selection is fully deterministic. You can now start JOINing tables from left to right
2.) Try small bits of querys on model database. Then you will see which selection works right and which doesn't do what you expected.

Comment: If `id` is unique in both `users` and `profile` table, a `GROUP BY` clause isn't necessary. Both of the queries in this answer avoid (and therefor seem to fix) the problem experienced with OP query without mentioning what the actual problem is... the unexpected (but well documented) "order of precedence" of the `AND` and `OR` operators.

Answer (score 0):

I think @SIDU has it in the comments: You are experiencing a Boolean order of operations problem. See also [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

For example:

```
SELECT 0 AND 0 OR 1 AS test;

+------+
| test |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

When doing complex statements with both `AND` and `OR`, use parenthesis. The operator order problem is leading to you doing an unintended outer join that's being masked by your `GROUP BY`. You shouldn't need a `GROUP BY` for that statement.

Although I don't personally care for the style @spencer7593 suggests in his answer(using `INNER JOIN`, etc.), it does have the advantage of preventing or identifying errors early for people new to SQL, so it's something to consider.